# VBA .Find() function not finding excell cell

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using the .Find function in workbook 1 to search for a number in a worksheet in workbook 2 and set it to a range object called "found".

I'm getting Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set. I know for a fact that the number exists in that second workbook, but I guess doesn't want to be found.  An interesting bug is that when I run this for the first time it will work fine.  But if I close workbook 1 and open it again, then the .Find function can't find the number anymore.

Can anyone see an apparent problem in my code below?

```
Dim found As Range
Dim ecrNum As String

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
ecrNum = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("H5")

'Opens ECR Log workbook
Set ECRlog = Workbooks.Open("filepath")
ECRlog.ActiveSheet.Unprotect ("x")

'Resets Filters in the ECR Log
If ECRlog.ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then
ECRlog.ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
End If

'Searches the ECR log for the specified ECR #
Set found = ECRlog.ActiveSheet.Range("C:C").Find(What:=ecrNum, _
            LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

'Pushes info from ECR form to ECR Log
ECRlog.ActiveSheet.Cells(found.Row, 5) = proj
ECRlog.ActiveSheet.Cells(found.Row, 6) = model
ECRlog.ActiveSheet.Cells(found.Row, 7) = ecn
ECRlog.ActiveSheet.Cells(found.Row, 9) = dueDate
```

Comment: You are relying on ActiveSheet too much. Don't you know the names of the worksheets involved?

Comment: `Workbooks.Open("filepath")` This does not look correct. Is the file actually called "filepath" or is it a variable? You are using it as a literal argument.

Comment: I assume your error is occurring on the `ECRlog.ActiveSheet.Cells(found.Row, 5) = proj` line, but it would be useful if your question explicitly said which line is giving the error so that we don't **have** to assume.

Comment: Correct. The error directs me to ECRlog.ActiveSheet.Cells(found.Row, 5) = proj and highlights "found".  And when I review it, nothing has been assigned to the "found" object.

In response to the other comments:
- I use ActiveSheet because there is only one sheet in that workbook.
- I put "filepath" in there just as a place holder.  The actual file path is in the program.

Comment: After setting `found` add: `If found Is Nothing Then Stop`. That will put it in break mode and you can manually compare the values between worksheets. My bet is there is no whole-match as defined in the `.Find` method: `LookAt:=xlWhole`. I usually run into leading or trailing spaces being the culprit, or data type issues (UPC set as number dropping leading zeros). If possible considering your requirements, you might try `LookAt:=xlPart`. Manually comparing is the only advice I have especially with shared workbooks that accumulate a lot of typos and junk. You'll have to sort through exceptions.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, Moondogs.  I tried the xlPart but unfortunately it did not help.  
And the "If found Is Nothing Then Stop" won't help me either because the two sheets are set up so that there will always be matching numbers between the two. Typos won't occur because the process of inputting these numbers into the two Workbooks is automated by my VBA program.  The number in this particular instance is 17020. I've checked the cells in both sheets and the number and formatting are exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

So I've been troubleshooting and testing this problem endlessly and believe I've identified the cause. The solution is trickier to identify (for me), but there is an easy workaround.

When workbook 1 runs the program but workbook 2 is already open, that's when I get the error.  When I close workbook 2 and run the program again, I don't get an error, and everything runs fine. So there must be a read/write issue that is preventing the `.find()` command from successfully finding the number it's looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Worksheet.Range returns a Range object that represents a cell or a range of cells. Taking into consideration `Set found = ECRlog.ActiveSheet.Range("C:C").Find(What:=ecrNum, _
            LookIn:=**xlValues**, LookAt:=xlWhole)` I believe you should try `ecrNum = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("H5").Value` instead of your fifth line of code. 
More on Worksheet.Range property [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-range-property-excel)